# Are selectOne and selectMany choices bounded by SelectItems?

Tags: java, validation, jsf, parameter-spoofing

Do the JSF selectOne and selectMany controls only allow submission of values defined in the given selectItems?  I'm concerned about parameter spoofing, and if this was built-in, I wouldn't require a validator to ensure the selected value was one of the valid choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, precisely. And no, you wouldn't require a validation to make sure no-parameter-spoofing. I remember, I needed to customize the behavior a year back , when the requirement was opposite.